# How to do method onPostExecute initiate new Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have one task that execute the method doInBackground and return a boolean value. What I want is to initiate a new Intent but the method startActivity is not available. How can I do that?

My task:

```
        public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

                 boolean sucess;

                 //do some stuff

                 return sucess;
            }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            if (result) {
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, MainViewActivity.class));
                            //it doesn't find startActivity
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A remark about previous replies:
Please remember to do not [leak your activity](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html). Use `WeakReference` class:

```
public static class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    WeakReference<Activity> mActivityReference;

    public LoginTask(Activity activity){
        this.mActivityReference = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

         boolean sucess;

         //do some stuff

         return sucess;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result && mActivityReference.get() != null) {
            Activity activity = mActivityReference.get();
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainViewActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the Activity that starts the AsyncTak in the constructor

```
public class LoginTask {
    private Context mCtx;

    public LoginTask(Context ctx){
        mCtx = ctx;
    }

    ....

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            mCtx.startActivity(new Intent(mCtx, MainViewActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the task with a reference to the activity or context that spawned it.

```java
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    Activity mActivity;

    public LoginTask(Activity activity){
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

         boolean sucess;

         //do some stuff

         return sucess;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MainViewActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that startActivity is not available? I just tested it and it works fine for me.

I think you should replace the **this** in your line, because the this doesn't refer to the Activity, it refers to the ASyncTask.

```
   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainViewActivity.class));
```

That should work.

Comment: startActivity is a function of a Context.  If his AsyncTask is not an inner class of his activity, it isn't directly available.  But @SimonSays suggestion would work.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside onPostExecute() refers to AsyncTask class instance.
Use `YourActivityName.this` instead:

```
startActivity(new Intent(ParentActivity.this, MainViewActivity.class));
```